# How do I bind a value to a textbox in Angular2?

Tags: date, angular, typescript, kendo-ui

I have been trying to figure out how to bind a value to a textbox in Angular2. Currently I have a textbox with a placeholder that is loaded with a predetermined value.

`<input id="textbox" class="k-textbox" placeholder={{label}}  />`

But once I change a value of a date component, I would want the placeholder value to be updated to the date value selected. So far i wrote this but this doesn't seem to be working. Please advice.

***date-component.html***

```
<input id="datepicker" (input)="changeLabel()"/>
```

---

***date-component.ts***

```
label:string;
constructor() {
    this.label = 'Select Date';
}
changeLabel() {
    this.label = 'Date Selected';
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try: <input id="textbox" class="k-textbox" [placeholder]="label"  />

Comment: @galvan yes I did. But nothing happens even after selecting the date component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an `click` event to propagate the changes.

**date-component.html**

`<input id="datepicker" (click)="changeLabel()"/> //<-- click event`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now it did change after doing the following.

<input id="textbox" class="k-textbox" [placeholder]="label"  />

<input id="datepicker" (click)="changeLabel()"/>

Only after I click inside the textbox, the date changes. Is there a way for it to update the textbox after the date has been selected, instead of me clicking inside the textbox?

Something along the line of 'onchange' ?

Comment: `placeholder={{label}} `  and `[placeholder] ="label"` are doing the same thing  - INTERPOLATION. you can use either to property bind values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two way databinding with NgModel.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel

Basically this would make "label" change to whatever the user types.

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="label" id="datepicker" />
```

You will also need to import FormsModule in your app.
Plunker to show what I mean:
https://plnkr.co/edit/CfmalT7GesrP5lzBsNFx?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

use keyup Event

```
<input (keyup)="changeLabel()">
```

enter the value its call the keyup event